# How to express an invalid argument such as "affirming the consequent" in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus

For example, say you want to write a symbolic statement for affirming the consequent. You could write it in the following two ways
$$
(P \to Q, Q) \to P
$$
or
$$
\frac{P \to Q, Q}{P}
$$
Which one should be used? Is it mostly a difference in taste/preference, or is one more favourable than another, or perhaps are there circumstances where one is used instead of the other?

Comment: The first one can be recovered using the general form $(\Gamma, \varphi)$ where the *set* $\Gamma$ of formulas is the set of premises and $\varphi$ is the conclusion. Thus, MP will be $(\{ \alpha \to \beta, \alpha \}, \beta)$.

Comment: Having said that, regarding the title question, you may simply write: $P \to Q, Q \nvDash P$ that means: "the conclusion does **not** follow from the premises".

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen the first one … and for good reason: it uses the symbol $\to$ both as a logic symbol (a symbol *of* the language of logic) as well as a meta-logic symbol (a symbol that is used to say something *about* logic), and you really want to separate those two.

But the second way is a pretty standard to express an inference, sure! Another common notation is $P \to Q, Q \therefore P$

Comment: Ah, then [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent) has an error. I am not surprised.

Comment: I suppose a follow up question would then be, what is better to use, the one with the turnstile, or the one with the horizontal bar/fraction format?

Comment: @Kalcifer The turnstile is used more in text (i.e. in a paragraph), while the horizontal bar is used either for emphasis of a particular result or when the deductions need to be graphically organized in a way — e.g. constructing a tree, either a semantic or proof-theoretic one. Both are perfectly fine to use, but I'd guess the turnstile is more frequent.

Comment: @Kalcifer Yeah, that notation in the Wikipedia page is unusual at best  … and I would say that overloading the $\to$ symbol like that is confusing and just really inappropriate.

Comment: Great answer except I don't believe using the turnstile $\vdash$ to express an invalid argument such as $P \to Q, Q \vdash P$ is correct because the turnstile means that a conclusion is provable from a set of premises and the premises $P \to Q, Q$ do *not* prove $P$ in propositional logic.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy 'provable' means 'provable using a certain set of inference rules', so ultimately 'provability' is always relative to a particular proof system. Indeed, we really should always index the turnstyle, and say something like $\phi \vdash_{S} \psi$ to say that 'system $S$ can derive $\psi$ from $\phi$'.  Of course, we typically assume that whatever proof system we work with is sound and complete, so then $\vdash$ collapses to $\vDash$, and as such we can remove the system reference. But at least theoretically, a proof system can 'prove' invalid inferences

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, what is provable is relative to the formal system in question. The OP stated propositional logic was being used (in the title). In that case, the turnstile $\vdash$ is not an appropriate way of expressing the argument $P \to Q, Q \vdash P$.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy But different proof systems can be defined relative to propositional logic, including ones that allow invalid inferences. Anyway, I think a much better reason not to use the $\vdash$ is that the OP simply wants to express this inference or argument, rather than make a claim about the provability of this inference. So, the horizontal line is good, and so would the $\therefore$... and so you're right, the $\vdash$ is probably not good, but I would say not so much for the reason you state.

Comment: Looks like I have homework to do! Thanks for the feedback, @Bram28

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy And thank you for yours!  Made me realize that $\vdash$ is indeed not a good way to express an inference, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a means of expressing an argument without actually asserting it is valid or invalid. So, if you want to express that $P$ *allegedly* follows from the premises $Q, P \to Q$, then the convention is to use a symbol such as the colon ":" or therefore sign "$\therefore$" or even the double slash "//"as follows

$$ Q, P \to Q : P \\
   Q, P \to Q \therefore P \\
   Q, P \to Q \text{ // } P \\ $$

I've seen these symbols often used to express arguments whose validity is not yet decided. Such arguments may be referred to as sequents. Tomassi expounds on this idea in his book [Logic](https://emilkirkegaard.dk/en/wp-content/uploads/Paul-Tomassi-Logic.pdf) beginning on page $43$.

I do *not* suggest using the turnstile "$\vdash$" to formally express an argument unless your intent is to assert the conclusion is provable from the premises in a given system. This is because the turnstile "$\vdash$" has a very specific meaning, that is, a sentence of the form

$$ P_1,P_2,...,P_n \vdash C $$

not only *alleges* that $C$ follows from the premises $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ but also makes the stronger claim that $C$ is in fact a logical consequence of the premises, provable from the formulas $P_1,P_2,...,P_n$ using the inference rules of the given system.

So, if you cannot prove $P$ is a logical consequence of the premises $Q, P \to Q$ in the system you're working with, then using the turnstile to express

$$ Q, P \to Q \vdash P $$

would be patently incorrect. In fact, the argument $ Q, P \to Q : P $ is an invalid argument form referred to as "affirming the consequent" in all propositional systems I'm aware of (although it could certainly be a valid argument in other systems). In such cases, writing

$$ Q, P \to Q \nvdash P $$

would be correct, stating that $Q, P \to Q$ does not prove $P$.

I also agree with the comments made about using the arrow and horizontal bar.

Answer (score 0):

> How to express an invalid argument such as "affirming the consequent"
> in propositional logic?

We can say that $((P\to Q)\land Q) \to P$ is a contingency, i.e. it is sometimes true, and sometimes false.

The truth table:

[image]

Specifically, we can formally state that $(((P\to Q)\land Q) \to P)\iff (Q\to P)$

The truth table:

[image]